# Darknet OpenCV found but can't demo

Tags: opencv, darknet, demo

```
-- Found OpenCV: C:/OpenCV/build (found version "3.4.12")
```

^^ when I run cmake . it shows found opencv but when i try to use darknet.exe detector demo ...

it displays

```
CUDA-version: 10020 (11020), cuDNN: 7.6.5, GPU count: 1
OpenCV isn't used - data augmentation will be slow
Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.
```

I have my makefile set to

```
OPENCV=1
```

and I ran cmake again but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by recompiling the all build in visual studios